# Temporarily link with Boost libraries in a test

Tags: cmake

I have a `CMakeLists.txt` file containing a simple `CHECK_CXX_SOURCE_COMPILES` test. For that test I need to add the Boost libraries when it links, but only for that test. I have already checked that the Boost library exists.

Can it be done? What variable(s) should I add `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable you are looking for is `CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES`:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
check_cxx_source_compiles("int main() { ... }" MY_CODE_COMPILES)
```